# Массив с изменяющимся размером

Tags: c#, массивы

Вопрос такой: как сделать так, чтобы массив, например, когда вводим с консоли увеличивался, то есть можно вводить очень много раз данные пока мы не введем определенную комбинацию символов для окончания работы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А как же, аналог из VB **`ReDim Preserve`**?

```
Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 1);
```

[Array.Resize Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Это решает задачу, но неэффективно: здесь будет копирование массива.

Comment: Но, это делается на более низком уровне, нежели, копирование вручную. Также, **не обязательно при каждом вводе вызывать** эту функцию, а можно например, каждые 20 вводов и увеличивать сразу на 20.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe,
> Также, не обязательно при каждом вводе вызывать эту функцию, а можно например, каждые 20 вводов и увеличивать сразу на 20.
Это называется `List`.

Answer (score 7):

Это называется динамический массив.

1) Если вам важна именно реализация, т.е. как это делается внутри различных оберток и структур данных вроде списков, билдеров и прочего.

**Решение:** создать сперва массив определенного размера, затем если данных становится больше чем может вместить массив, то создаете новый и больший по размеру. Копируете в его начало элементы из старого массива и старый массив уничтожаете, а новый используете для накопления. Если он заполнился то повторяете процедуру. После ввода помечаете конец массива или создаете новый и точно подогнанный по размеру, и уже работаете.

2) Если вам нужен результат.

**Решение:** то просто используете средства языка, например List<T> после ввода данных вызываете метод ToArray() или подобный и присваиваете полученное значение ссылке типа массив. Например

```
int[] arr = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Метод Add() объявлен в интерфейсе [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30ft6hw7(v=vs.90).aspx), посмотрите его наследников, вам подойдет (для добавления новых элементов) любой из них.

Не знаю вашей задачи, но почти уверен что вам нужен именно [List<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.90).aspx) (это то что, о чем здесь говорили выше уже).

Answer (score 2):

Простой ответ - никак. В .NET массивы имеют постоянный размер. Но можно сначала добавлять элементы в `List`, а потом создать массив длиной, равной длине списка, и скопировать элементы.

Comment: Лучше вместо «потом создать массив длиной, равной длине списка, и скопировать элементы» просто вызвать у листа метод ToArray(). (И не забыть добавить «using System.Linq;» к юзингам, конечно.)

Comment: @dog_funtom, да. )

Comment: а можно поподробнее?

Comment: ... а ещё лучше просто работать с `List<>`.